# Having issue with select statement

Tags: c#, linq, list, select, ienumerable

I have this method

```
public CreateModule GetModuleDetails(long id)
{
    var module = (_dbSis.Modules.Where(t => t.Id == id).Select(m => new CreateModule
    {
        Id = id,
        ModuleId = m.ModuleId,
        TypeName = m.ModuleType.TypeName,
        KindName = m.ModuleType.ModuleKind.KindName,
        Properties = m.PropertyConfiguration.PropertyInstances.Select(
            x => new Property { Name = x.Property.Name, Value = x.Value })
    }));

    return (module.FirstOrDefault());
}
```

In this method lets say module with **Id** 40 has two Property Name and two property Values. I wanted to have a function that returns just two of those Property names and values, so basically **Properties** field from above function which is of type **IEnumerable**. I did this which doesn't work right now

```
 public List<Property> GetModuleProperties(long id)
 {
     var moduleProperties = _dbSis.Modules.Where(m => m.Id == id).SelectMany(p => new Property()
     {
         Name = p.PropertyConfiguration.PropertyInstances.Select(z=>z.Property.Name),
         Value = p.PropertyConfiguration.PropertyInstances.Select(x=>x.Value)
     });
      return (moduleProperties);
  }
```

But the line Where i assign `Name` and `Value` using Linq shows an error, because linq expression returns two names for `Name` field and two Values for `Value` field.

How can I solve this, so that the method returns a proper list of values?

Actually, right now this module has two property names: Physical ID, and FirmwareVersion and two values: 123456 and 1.02.

Comment: What does "doesn't work right" mean? It "shows an error"? What is the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want:

```
return _dbSis.Modules.Where(t => t.Id == id)
    .SelectMany(m => m.PropertyConfiguration.PropertyInstances)
    .Select(i => new Property { Name = i.Property.Name, Value = i.Value })
    .ToList();
```

or alternatively:

```
return _dbSis.Modules.Where(t => t.Id == id)
    .SelectMany(m => m.PropertyConfiguration.PropertyInstances.Select(i => new Property {
        Name = i.Property.Name,
        Value = i.Value
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Yup. I tried with select many but didn't have tolist in the end. This solved the isse